# Saving an image with shell_exec() - using imagejpeg & jpegoptim, with stdin / stdinout

Tags: php, shell-exec, jpegoptim

I'm saving an image twice, once when I create it with imagejpeg and then I compress and overwrite with jpegoptim. How may I do this in one swoop, so I'm not saving the image twice?

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($imageString);
imagejpeg($im, 'img/test.jpg', 100);
shell_exec("jpegoptim img/test.jpg");
```

Jpegoptim have [stdin and stdout](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim/issues/14), but I'm struggling to understand how to use them.

I want to save the image with the shell, so I imagine something like this:

```
imagejpeg($im);
shell_exec("jpegoptim --stdin > img/test.jpg");
```

But alas, it doesn't work how I imagined.

Comment: You do need a pipe: [`popen`](http://php.net/popen). Because `imagejpeg` and `shell_exec` don't share anything just because they're written after one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although that might not perform better, this is a solution that writes nothing but the final result to disk:

```
// I'm not sure about that, as I don't have jpegoptim installed 
$cmd = "jpegoptim --stdin > img/test.jpg";
// Use output buffer to save the output of imagejpeg
ob_start(); 
imagejpeg($img, NULL, 100); 
imagedestroy($img); 
$img = ob_get_clean();
// $img now contains the binary data of the jpeg image
// start jpegoptim and get a handle to stdin 
$handle = popen($cmd, 'w');
// write the image to stdin
fwrite($handle, $img."\n");
```

Don't forget to close all handles afterwards if your script keeps running.